# Assert Error in SQLAlchemy Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying to set up a basic SQLAlchemy db and a base class, but I've been having issues with just calling the function to create_all(). Here is the error:

```
File "C:/dev/FishFaceStreams/projects/branches/rushill/db_poc/main.py", line 54, in <module>
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5558, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3220, in _run_ddl_visitor
    conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2427, in _run_ddl_visitor
    visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 677, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 907, in visit_metadata
    [t for t in tables if self._can_create_table(t)]
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 907, in <listcomp>
    [t for t in tables if self._can_create_table(t)]
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 872, in _can_create_table
    return not self.checkfirst or not self.dialect.has_table(
  File "<string>", line 2, in has_table
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 88, in cache
    return fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\rushi\Desktop\PyEnv\db_poc\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\base.py", line 2672, in has_table
    assert schema is not None
AssertionError
```

I think the error has something ti do with schema not being created. Issue is, I thought I have done that through code. Would love some help on this. Here is the code :

```
import traceback
import dbconfig
import logConfig as config
import logging, os, sys
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

# logger setup
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler = loggingfile_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.path.join(config.logPath,(config.logFilename).replace('event','soccerevents')))
file_handler.setFormatter(config.logFormat)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# Set up connection url - format: user, pass, host, port
url = 'mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}'.format(dbconfig.mysql['user'], dbconfig.mysql['passwd'], dbconfig.mysql['host'], 3306)

# setup base class
Base = declarative_base()

# try engine setup with connection url
try:
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Error in creating engine: " + str(e) + traceback.format_exc())
    sys.exit(-1)


# create session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Session.configure(bind=engine)

session = Session()

# user model class
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
            self.name,
            self.fullname,
            self.nickname,
        )
try:
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Error in create all base class tables : " + str(e) + traceback.format_exc())
    sys.exit(-1)

# add User model
ed_user = User(name="ed", fullname="Ed Jones", nickname="edsnickname")
session.add(ed_user)
```

Comment: What does the engine url  look like?

Comment: mysql://{db_name}:{passwd}@127.0.0.1:3306. Can't reveal the db and password for obvious reasons

Comment: It should be `mysql://user:password@host:port/dbname`

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! What about the case where I haven't created a db yet?

Comment: You could create a new engine with the right url. Or you might be able to get away with something like `with engine.connect() as conn:conn.execite('USE mydb')`

Comment: @snakecharmerb why is the '/dbname' needed and causing the error in case if its absent?

Comment: @Vicrobot SQLA needs to know which database it is going to create the tables in, so it asserts that the value is defined (hence the error).  I would guess that this is more robust than relying on the user connecting to the right database via some configuration mechanism.